# Are there differences between SMD capacitors indicated by their colors?

Tags: capacitor, surface-mount, colour-coding

I have been fixing a graphics card that has PCB damage, and I noticed some missing SMD capacitors. I replaced them with capacitors of approximately the same size, but the color is different.

Are there differences between SMD capacitors indicated by their colors?

[image]

Comment: Nope. Depends on the manufacturer, series etc. but has no general meaning.

Comment: "replaced them with capacitors of approximately the same size." Size is even less of an indicator than color.  There are dozens of capacitor values available in the same physical size.

Comment: Remove one of the neighbouring ones of the same size and measure it. They're likely all the same judging from the picture.

Comment: "missing" as in clear result of some damage, or just empty pads that were never populated? The more complex PCB is the more chances you will find some empty pads that are not supposed to have components on them. Those R2107 and C2108 for example.

Comment: @Unimportant How did you come to that conclusion? There is no repeating pattern that I can see. Probably, maybe. Likely would be a stretch.

Comment: @Maple experience with graphics cards. These locations with all those vias are the back side of the memory chips. All the larger decoupling caps tend to be the same there.

Comment: @Unimportant ah, that makes sense then. my experience with graphic cards is limited to plugging them into motherboards... sometimes sideways.

Answer (score 1):

your best bet would be to measure the capacity of the similar-sized capacitors near the missing ones and order one of the appropriate footprint and capacity.

Comment: Yeah diffinetely gonna do this. Thanks